# Why the Bin type in Aerospike java client doesn't implement java.util.Map

Tags: aerospike

I'm migrating our database from MongoDB to Aerospike, so I'm expecting the Bin type in Aerospike's Java client to implement `java.util.Map<String, Object>`, but discovered that the Bin is defined as:

```
public final class Bin {
```

yet from what I understand, the Bin is like a map (name->value).

So why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a flexible design and future proof. As of today it has only name and value. So, map is enough. In the future, if you want to set/get additional properties like bin-level ttl, or persistence etc, this design will allow that.

Comment: When you say bin-level ttl, are you saying that in the future we can have different TTLs for different bins in a single record?

Comment: Yes, that's been a common feature request.